# windows 10 crashes explorer.exe upon opening file explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Ok I have an issue. On 3 separate computers that i have updated to windows 10 in the past week whenever I try to open a file explorer window via either taskbar pinning, Win + E, or start > file explorer It crashes and restarts explorer.exe

If I open a folder or a shortcut to a folder on the desktop it works fine.

Comment: Open [Reliability Monitor](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/troubleshoot-explorer-crashes-checklist/#reliability) and see if there are any critical entries listed for Windows Explorer. It may show the 3rd party module causing the crash.

Comment: look if you can generate a crash dump: http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU if yes, share the dmp, I'll analyze it

Comment: have you captured the dump of the explorer crash or is the issue gone?